# Adding argument to form action using input type hidden

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How to add arguments in a form action using input type="hidden". 
My HTML snippet...

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="txt"/>
<input type="hidden" name="usID" value=123/>
<input type="hidden" name="usname" value="name1"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="add()" value="ADD"/>
</form>
```

My JavaScript snippet...

```
function add()
{
document.getElementsByName('usID').value=789;
document.getElementsByName('usname').value="name2";

document.getElementById('form1').action = "/page";
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

After entering "text" in the textbox and pressing ADD, the link looks like this...
http://localhost:3000/page?txt=text&usID=123&usname=name1

Why hasn't the usID and usname changed to 789 and "name2" respectively?
Any other alternative if not this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` is going to return a collection of html elements (NodeList), not a single html element. meaning the return value doesnt have a `value` attribute that will change the input. you need to either give them an `id` and find them with `getElementById` and then change the value, or grab the first element of your collection

```
document.getElementsByName('usname')[0].value="name2";
```

or (preferred way)

```
<input type="hidden" name="usname" value="name1" id="usname"/>

function add(){
  document.getElementById('usname').value="name2";
  ...
}
```

though i have to ask, is there a reason you're changing the hidden field element like this?

Comment: Basically I had to pass values from database in form action. I was under this misconception that if we add value initially in the `<input>` then only we will be able to add/modify its value later.
Secondly, I realized now that value of name forms a component of the link and not the value of id.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

this help you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
           function add()
                {
                     var usID = document.forms["frm"]["usID"];
                     var usname = document.forms["frm"]["usname"];
                    usID.value=789;
                    usname.value="name2";
                   document.getElementById('form1').action = "/page";
                   document.getElementById('form1').submit();
                }
        </script>

        <h3>Please select the <span>first letter</span> of your <span>last name</span>: </h3>

            <form id="form1" name="frm">
            <input type="text" name="txt"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="usID" value=123/>
            <input type="hidden" name="usname" value="name1"/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="add()" value="ADD"/>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this helps. I was making mistake in accessing the elements by `document.getElementsByName` approach.
Thank you!